# Java - How to find out which Jar file an import comes from?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

The project I'm working on has about 10 jar files as libraries.  At the top of one of the files there's an import statement like:

```
import jpe.nar.crat.maker.ObjectMakerFactory;
```

Is there a way to tell which Jar file it comes from?

(I'm using Netbeans if that matters.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`CodeSource#getLocation()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/CodeSource.html#getLocation%28%29) for this. The [`CodeSource`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/CodeSource.html) is available by [`ProtectionDomain#getCodeSource()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html#getCodeSource%28%29). The [`ProtectionDomain`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html) in turn is available by [`Class#getProtectionDomain()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getProtectionDomain%28%29).

```
URL location = ObjectMakerFactory.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
System.out.println(location.getPath());
// ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried doing a 'Open Declaration' on the class? In Eclipse, when you do it, it opens a window that shows the name of the jar and tells you that this jar has 'No Source Attachment'. I am hoping something similar should happen for NetBeans.

Thanks,
R

Comment: In Eclipse, do an 'Open Declaration'. In Project Explorer, click the "Link with Editor" yellow-two-arrow-button. The class file that opens in the editor will map itself to the jar and package on the left hand side in Project Explorer.

Answer (score 3):

I like **JFind** very much:

http://jfind.sourceforge.net/

... it works recursively by looking into jar's, inside war's, inside ear's, etc...

If you wrap the java launcher in a shell script and put that on your PATH, it becomes a very powerful tool:

I.e. to find all `EntityManager` classes in directory `jboss-6.0.0.20100429-M3` :

```
$ jfind.sh EntityManager ./jboss-6.0.0.20100429-M3
Search String: EntityManager
Windows Search Location: jboss-6.0.0.20100429-M3

....jjj.jjjjjjjjjjj
ClassName = javax/persistence/EntityManager.class
JarName = jboss-6.0.0.20100429-M3\client\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar
----------------


jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj
jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj
ClassName = org/apache/xerces/impl/XMLEntityManager.class
JarName = jboss-6.0.0.20100429-M3\client\xercesImpl.jar
----------------
```

A little shell wrapper for use in Cygwin:

```
if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` <classname> [<fromDir>]"
  exit 1
fi

echo Search String: $1
SEARCH_LOCATION=`cygpath -w $2`
echo Windows Search Location: $SEARCH_LOCATION

java -jar `cygpath -w $HOME/bin/JFind.jar` "$1" "$SEARCH_LOCATION"
echo
```

Answer (score 3):

In the Netbeans IDE:
In your code, ctrl-select the class name.  After the relevant java file comes up in the editor (if you don't have source for the class, it might not show much).  Right-click anywhere in the source window and select "Select In Projects".  The class will show highlighted in the jar where it came from.

This has been working at least as far back as Netbeans 8.0.

Comment: Note, this won't work for something like `import netscape.javascript.*;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Jar Class Search](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=15286) for netbeans. I'm not sure that it still compatible, but it's worth the try.

Answer (score 1):

Programmaticly or interactively?

You can try [DocJar](http://www.docjar.com/). In Eclipse control click on the item will show you (the edit panel will show the source (if attached) or the methods available while Package Explorer will open the tree to the class), I would be surprised if Netbeans did not behave in a similar manor.

Answer (score 0):

A former colleague of mine, Tom, wrote JarSniffer (http://sourceforge.net/projects/jarsniffer/). It's a handy little tool to find a class in a set of jars, zips and directory trees.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse just do Ctrl-Click on the class name (in import sentence), then Right- Click on .class code, to open a dialog,·and finally chose Declarations-project.

[image]